# Formal Methods, Logic and VDM past exam paper questions

Tags: methods, logic, formal-languages, formal-methods

I was hoping someone can help me with the following questions, answers would be best but if you can point me in the right direction that will be helpful also.
I am a final year uni student and these questions are from a previous exam on Formal Methods and I could do with knowing the answers ready for this years paper. Our lecturer does not seem the best and has not covered a lot of this and so finding the exact answer has been proving impossible. Google has not been much of a help nor has the recommended books.

1 - Given that ∃x • P (x) is logically equivalent to ¬∀x • ¬P (x) and that
∀x ∈ S • P (x) means ∀x • x ∈ S ⇒ P (x), deduce that ∃x ∈ S • P (x)
means ∃x • x ∈ S ∧ P (x)

2 - Describe the two statements that would have to be proved to show that
the definition:

```
max(i, j)
if i>j
then i
else j
```

is a correct implementation of the specification:

```
max(i : Z, j : Z)r : Z
pre true
post (r = i ∨ r = j) ∧ i ≤ r ∧ j ≤ r
```

Comment: Do you know that ∃ means "there exists" and ∀ means "for all"?  Do you also know that ∈ means "in the set"?

Comment: ∃x • P (x) is equivalent to ¬∀x • ¬P (x) because if there exists at least one x for which P(x) is true then logically not P(x) is true for not all of the x's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is really just manipulation of symbols using the given and two other well-known logical equivalences:

```
(1) ∃x • P(x) is logically equivalent to ¬∀x • ¬P(x)
(2) ∀x∈S • P(x) means ∀x • x∈S ⇒ P(x)

∃x∈S • P(x)
== ¬∀x∈S • ¬P(x) (from (1))
== ¬∀x • x∈S ⇒ ¬P(x) (from (2))
== ¬∀x • ¬x∈S v ¬P(x) (from def. of ⇒)
== ¬∀x • ¬(x∈S ∧ P(x)) (from ¬A v ¬B == ¬(A ∧ B))
== ∃x • x∈S ∧ P(x) (from (1) -- the other way around)
```

For the second, you need to recognize that the outcome of `max(i, j)` will be computed along one of two paths: one, when `i<j` and the other when `i>=j` (the logical negation of `i<j`)

So you need to show that

1. if `true ∧ i<j` (precondition), then `(r=i ∨ r=j) ∧ i≤r ∧ j≤r` (post condition), and
2. if `true ∧ i>=j` (precond.) then `(r=i ∨ r=j) ∧ i≤r ∧ j≤r` (post cond.),

where `r` is the result of `max(i, j)`

Comment: This is a great answer indeed.

Answer (score 1):

But section 2 of your question does not make sense since any implementation that returns either i or j is correct.

The specification is wrong.

A correct postcondition is

```
post (i > j => r = i) v (i <= j => r = j)
```